# How to check Bluetooth On/Off state in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

How can I check whether my device's bluetooth is turned on or off?

I have tried `ispoweron()` method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Do your usual operations with Bluetooth. If they throw `BluetoothStateException`, then Bluetooth is off.